# Unable to automate a radio button using selenium web driver

Tags: selenium

Unable to automate a radio button using selenium web driver.

Element is identified as below.

Someone please let me know how to select this radio button.
I am able to do it using Xpath people say that its not good to use Xpath.

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML code snippet for the radio button.

Comment: what does "unable" mean? Do you get an error? Does the program crash?

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath here. What you have to do is somehow you need to isolate that element uniquely. You can use id/xpath/css/..etc..

if the radio button is like follow

```html
<form action="">
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

You can uniquely filter by value

Ex1:   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=\"male\"]")).click();

Ex2:   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='male']")).click();